# Random image with link on load, without loading them all

Tags: javascript

I do not want all of the images to load, only the one randomly chosen image. I cannot figure out if the other images are hidden but loading in the background. Each image needs a hyperlink attached.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
function banner() { } ; b = new banner() ; n = 0
b[n++]= "<a href='#'><img src='main_theme/top_gallery/gallery1.jpg' /></a>"
b[n++]= "<a href='#'><img src='main_theme/top_gallery/gallery2.jpg' /></a>"
b[n++]= "<a href='#'><img src='main_theme/top_gallery/gallery3.jpg' /></a>"
b[n++]= "<a href='#'><img src='main_theme/top_gallery/gallery4.jpg' /></a>"
b[n++]= "<a href='#'><img src='main_theme/top_gallery/gallery5.jpg' /></a>"
i=Math.floor(Math.random() * n) ; 
document.write( b[i] )
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: why have you tagged this as jQuery? Never-mind how terrible this is, there certainly isn't any jQuery involved.

Comment: I apologize, been coding all day and forgot its not jquery related. Just looking for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the chosen image (the one in `b[i]`) should get loaded. You only have simple uninterpreted strings until you call `document.write`, then one of your strings gets interpreted as HTML and the browser will discover that there is an image to load.

You could clear your browser cache and watch your web server's access logs to verify my claims.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your existing code.  Only one image will get written in the document.write() call.  Everything else is just a string in memory.  The code could be cleaned up a lot through.  I would suggest changing your code to this:

```
writeRandomImage(baseURL, max) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
    var str = "<a href='#'><img src='" + baseURL + rand + ".jpg' /></a>";
    document.write(str);
}

writeRandomImage("main_theme/top_gallery/gallery", 5);
```

This should also eliminate any concerns about any other images being loaded since the other URLs aren't even constructed.

Comment: Elegant! But how would I pass custom links to each image?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  This function was based on the example you posted.  If you want to change the baseURL, just pass a different value in the function call to writeRandomImage.  If you want each image to be completely different and not algorithmically related as in your example, then you can create an array of the candidate URLs, pass that into the function and choose a random index from the array.